# How to using custom colormap with pixel calculation, gray scale value by opencv and make it workable on camera

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, image, opencv

I tried to implement the mcolor colormap in the [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/337325520_Comparison_and_performance_evaluation_of_human_bio-field_visualization_algorithm)
at page 8 to 10.

I developed the code to process a [image file](https://www.chinasona.org/Thiaoouba/White-Person.jpg) and it works ok.
Now, I want to adopt this image processing method to the camera which is captured by opencv.
I implemented it by python and opencv.
It looks like that it's not workable as the computing limitation.
Can anyone give me the direction to improve it?
I expected to adopt my image processing algorithm to all frames of camera.
Thank you.
Below is my complete source code of python

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_new = np.ones([img.shape[0], img.shape[1], 3], np.uint8)
    mcolor = np.ones([img.shape[0], img.shape[1], 3], np.uint8)
    for i in range(img.shape[0]):
        for j in range(img.shape[1]):
            val = img_gray[i][j] % 36
            if img_gray[i][j] <= 72:
                if val >= 1 and val <= 6:
                    mcolor[i][j] = (0, 0, 35)
                elif val >= 7 and val <= 12:
                    mcolor[i][j] = (i * 10, 0, 0)
                elif val >= 13 and val <= 18:
                    mcolor[i][j] = (1, 0, 35)
                elif val >= 19 and val <= 24:
                    mcolor[i][j] = (i * 20, 0, i * 20)
                elif val >= 25 and val <= 30:
                    mcolor[i][j] = (i * 10, i * 5, i * 5)
                elif val >= 31 and val <= 36:
                    mcolor[i][j] = (i * 10, 0, i * 4)
            elif img_gray[i][j] >= 73 and img_gray[i][j] <= 240:
                if val >= 1 and val <= 6:
                    mcolor[i][j] = (0, 0, i * 6)
                elif val >= 7 and val <= 12:
                    mcolor[i][j] = (0, i * 6, i * 6)
                elif val >= 13 and val <= 18:
                    mcolor[i][j] = (0, i * 6, 0)
                elif val >= 19 and val <= 24:
                    mcolor[i][j] = (i * 6, i * 6, 0)
                elif val >= 25 and val <= 30:
                    mcolor[i][j] = (i * 6, 0, i * 6)
                elif val >= 31 and val <= 36:
                    mcolor[i][j] = (i * 6, 0, 0)
            elif img_gray[i][j] > 241:
                if val >= 1 and val <= 6:
                    mcolor[i][j] = (0, i * 10, 30)
                elif val >= 7 and val <= 12:
                    mcolor[i][j] = (0, i * 10, 30)
                elif val >= 13 and val <= 18:
                    mcolor[i][j] = (0, i * 10, 30)
                elif val >= 19 and val <= 24:
                    mcolor[i][j] = (i * 10, 0, 0)
                elif val >= 25 and val <= 30:
                    mcolor[i][j] = (i * 10, 0, 0)
                elif val >= 31 and val <= 36:
                    mcolor[i][j] = (i * 10, 0, 0)

    for i in range(img.shape[0]):
        for j in range(img.shape[1]):
            b1, g1, r1 = img[i][j]
            r2, g2, b2 = mcolor[i][j]
            r, g, b = (
                min(round((int(r1) + int(r2) + 1) / 1.2), 255),
                min(round((int(g1) + int(g2) + 1) / 1.2), 255),
                min(round((int(b1) + int(b2) + 1) / 1.2), 255),
            )
            img_new[i][j] = (r, g, b)

    cv2.imshow("live", img_new)
    # cv2.imwrite("img_new.jpeg", img_new)
    # cv2.waitKey(0)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: "It looks like that it's not workable as the computing limitation." Are you saying the code works, it's just too slow? What happens if you reduce the framerate of your camera to a much lower value (0.5 FPS), does the program fully work at that point? At the moment, you're not doing any rate-limiting at all it seems.

Comment: In the paper, I find mcolor's use in `((I(x, y, z) +  mcolor[GS(x, y) + 1, z))] /1.2)` to contradict its description *Matrix that consist of image pixel*. Faulty nesting of parentheses raises questions - is the z to do with *GS* or mcolor? I have no idea what a *limit for j from 1 to 6* is, or what the *row*s are - *GS(n) / 6* ?! I doubt (i, j) is a coordinate tuple. (Then, the image is *not* three dimensional - the z in *I(x, y, z)* is the *colour component* (r, g, or b)).

Comment: (I wish I never looked at pages outside the referred range.)

Comment: The algorithm is good image processing practice, but otherwise the cited paper is true, high-grade pseudoscientific nonsense.

Comment: Right, so. The algorithmic specification is internally inconsistent and rife with nonsense. The "lim" is not a limit; the author is attempting to describe a loop. And the colour mapping has overlapping indices for which the output is ambiguous. Given these internal inconsistencies, there is no such thing as a correct implementation.

Comment: Your implementation is not even close to what the paper intended. For fun, I wrote a vectorised implementation, and the results look the same as figure 14. But this entire endeavour is just so very, very silly.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at just the code, I find it difficult to see its purpose.
In particular, I don't find *colormap*:

Document your code. [In the code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring).

Define a function for the mapping presented.
Find or define a function to apply it to an image.

For non-negative values, `img_gray[i][j] % 36` may take on values from 0 up, but never 36 up.
Prefer

```
    if lower < val <= mid:
        pass  # handle lower range
    elif val <= upper:  # 1 comparison less than mid < val <= upper
        pass  # handle upper range
```

Consider a table-driven approach for populating `mcolor`.
While following the paper in separating cases that are handled identically increases recognisability, it sure looks off in the code without a comment. (Looks another error in the paper, at that - where does that `where i >= 240.` come from?)

While next to all the numeric literals in the paper look magic to me,
avoid *magic numbers* like `36` and `255`: give them names.

There are three occurrences of `min(round((int(r1) + int(r2) + 1) / 1.2), 255)`: define a function.
(isn't round((int(r1) + int(r2) + 1) / 2) equal to ceil((int(r1) + int(r2)) / 2)?)